# What is the meaning of $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln|-x|}{\ln|x|}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, critical-phenomena

I am now working out some critical exponent, and I encountered this result $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln|-x|}{\ln|x|}.$$ Can I write this equals to 1?
Here $x=\frac{T-T_{c}}{T_{c}}$ and $T_{c}$ is the critical temerature.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can write it equal to 1.
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln|-x|}{\ln|x|}$$
Is the same as:
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(x)}=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}1=1$$

Because $x$ is positive (as long as you're not using negative temperatures, in that case you would just reverse the sign of the argument if the quotient happens to be negative).